# Rails has_one ID issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I would like to have a **has_one** relationship, but having the reference id column on the model which has the `has_one` attribute.

I have in my project a `Guest` model which should have a one-to-one relationship to a `User`. Please don't tell me use roles, the `Guest` class has more functionality I need.

So what I need is to have:

```
class Guest < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user, :dependent => :delete
```

I want to have `user_id` in `Guest` model - there is no sense to have `guest_id` in `User` model since there are other users which are not guests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think thaha's answer looks great. If you want to avoid adding columns to User, you could reverse the association that he mentions:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_one :guest, :dependent => :destroy


class Guest < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :user
```

also see paragraph 2.1 here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Answer (score 1):

We can implement one to one association in both ways, try this

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :guest, :dependent => :destroy


class Guest < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user
```

Comment: I prefer not to touch the code of `User` since it is not related only to `Guest`.